# @ionic/react with capacitor crash when Ion-Input opens the device keyboard

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, ionic4, capacitor

I am working on an App created with React/Ionic/Capacitor. All works fine but I am testing an Ion-Modal and adding an `IonInput` control inside of the Modal. Sometimes when the IonInput get the focus and the keyboard fires the App crash, the Android Studio device closes the app and shows me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jss.myapp, PID: 11188
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.capacitorjs.plugins.keyboard.Keyboard$KeyboardEventListener.onKeyboardEvent(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at com.capacitorjs.plugins.keyboard.Keyboard$1.onGlobalLayout(Keyboard.java:104)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:1056)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

That error is showed randomly, but yesterday it was showing all the time that I opened the keyboard. The problem is present no matter the ADV devices that I choose.

This is my input element in the template

```
 <IonInput
   value={note.title}
   placeholder="Untitled"
   onIonChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'title')}
   className="add-note-input"
></IonInput>
```

The previous code is inside a single component called View for example and then in another component, I am putting in a modal component

```
<IonModal
    isOpen={showModal}
    cssClass="my-custom-class">
      <View note={something}/>
</IonModal>
```

Any Ideas around that?

Comment: We are having a similar problem - did you find a solution to this?